# How does the CPU know if it is accessing an unallocated memory location?

Tags: linux, cpu, x86

Based on my understanding, when the CPU is accessing some memory location, for example if it is setting the memory location with the address of `4` to the value `100`, it treats the address `4` as a virtual address, and find out the physical address that this virtual address points to using the currently loaded process page table.

This is an example of a process page table:

[image]

So in our example, the CPU will set the memory location with the physical address of `12346` to the value of `100`.

But how does the CPU knows if it is accessing a virtual address that doesn't have a physical address mapped to it, does a process page table have a flag that indicates this fact, for example does a process page table have something like an "Allocated?" flag:

[image]

Comment: @Philip Couling I have edited my question and added the x86 tag.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about Unix or Linux.

Comment: @muru is it not better to make a very minor edit to the question to bring it into topic without changing it's meaning.  This question is directly asking "How does the linux kernel inform the CPU that an area of virtual memory is unallocated".  Voting closed seems a bit harsh here.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I see no mention of the kernel in the rest of the question. I disagree with your edit and am rolling it back. There's nothing harsh about voting to close. That just means there are probably better places to post this.

Comment: @muru It is tagged as `linux`! The question is about an interface between CPU and linux kernel.  It is therefore about the kernel as much as it is about the CPU.  It does not need to mention the kernel for this to be the case.

Comment: @muru Any question about an interface, asking "how does side A know <thing from side b>" is synonymous with "how does side b tell side a about <thing>".  They are the same question! My edit did not change the meaning of the question, it simply clarified its relevance to this site.

Answer (score 1):

Since you’re asking about x86 specifically, I’ll use that architecture, but this works on most (if not all) architectures supporting memory paging.

x86 page tables have a “present” bit, which is used to indicate whether a page is present in memory. If it is, and permissions etc. allow it, the CPU (with the help of its MMU) handles memory accesses directly. Otherwise, it raises an exception, and the kernel can use the information in the page table entry and its own data structures to decide how to handle it: allocate a physical page, read data from disk, copy a physical page (for copy-on-write), etc.

Comment: *"Otherwise, it raises an exception, and the kernel can use the information in the page table entry and its own data structures to decide how to handle it: allocate a physical page, read data from disk, copy a physical page (for copy-on-write), etc."* And I assume that one of the information that the kernel can find in the information in the page table entry and its own data structures is that this virtual address does not point to any physical address (not in memory and not on disk), and in this case what happens? does the kernel terminate the process?

Comment: @user344653 yes, except the issue of on-disk or not will be entirely the domain of the kernel.   When virtual addresses are not mapped to physical memory, the "exception" causes the process to be suspended and the kernel is informed of the exception.  If the kernel has previously put the page on disk, the kernel will discover this in it's own structures and load the page back into physical memory.  The kernel then updates the CPU's page table with the new physical address and resumes the process right where it left off.

Comment: Ultimately if the memory was never allocated, the same exception is raised to the kernel and the kernel chooses to terminate the process.